# Method of Characteristic for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given the following partial differential equation with initial condition
$$tu_x+u_t=2t\cdot u,\;IV: u(x,0)=x.$$
So I apply the method of characteristic to solve this problem as following

Forming three characteristic equation

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=t,\;\frac{dt}{ds}=1,\; and\;\frac{du}{ds}=2t\cdot u $$
$$\frac{dt}{ds}=1\rightarrow dt = ds\rightarrow t = s+t_0\rightarrow t=s\;since\; t_0=0\; from\; IV$$
then
$$\frac{dx}{ds}=t\rightarrow \frac{dx}{ds}=s\rightarrow x=\frac{s^2}{2}+x_0$$
also for the last equation we have
$$\frac{du}{ds}=2t\cdot u\rightarrow \frac{du}{u}=2s\;dt\rightarrow u=e^{s^2+u_0}$$
Then we substitute the $s=t$, and $x_0=x-\frac{s^2}{2}$ to initial condition
$$ u(x_0,0)=e^{0+u_0}=x\rightarrow u_0=lnx$$
Thus the finial solution I have should be $u(x,t)=e^{t^2+lnx}=xe^{t^2}$

However this is not same as the answer given, could someone tell me where I make the mistake in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$tu_x-u_t=tu$$
Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{tu}=ds$$
This is what you correctly found, but presented on an equivalent form.

A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{dt}{1}$ :
$$t^2-2x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{tu}$ :
$$ue^{-x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$ue^{-x}=F(t^2-2x)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined later in order to satisfy the initial condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=e^xF(t^2-2x)}$$

CONDITION :

$$u(x,0)=x=e^xF(-2x)$$
$$F(-2x)=xe^{-x}$$
Let $x=-\frac12 X$
$$F(X)=-\frac12 X  e^{\frac12 X}$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=t^2-2x$

$F(t^2-2x)=-\frac12 (t^2-2x)  e^{\frac12 (t^2-2x)}$
$$u(x,t)=e^x\left(-\frac12 (t^2-2x)  e^{\frac12 (t^2-2x)}\right)$$
After simplification, the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition is :
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=(x-\frac{t^2}{2})e^{\frac12 t^2}}$$

Comment: Sorry, Why we could write C2 = F(C1)?

Comment: This is a well known property for first order quasilinear PDEs without using boundary condition (Using boundary condition is another way if you prefer). Intuitive oversimplified explanation : Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants they are an infinity of equations such as $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ with arbitrary function $\Phi$. Or equivalently on the form of any relationship between the two arbitrary constants : $c_2=F(c_1)$ or equivalently $c_1=G(c_2)$ with arbitrary functions $F$ and $G$ one inverse of the other.